# How to recursively extract values from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  [3, 2, 5, 2],
  [8, 5, 4, 2],
  [9, 0, 8, 6],
  [9, 2, 7, 1],
  [1, 9, 2, 3],
  [8, 1, 1, 6],
  [8, 8, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 3, 0],
  [2, 4, 5, 3],
  [4, 0, 9, 7]
])
```

I am trying to write a recursive function that extracts all the possible paths up until 3 iterations:

[image]

and saves them into a list. Several attempts but no results to post.

Desired Output:

```
[
    [0, 3, 9, 4],
    [0, 3, 9, 0],
    [0, 3, 9, 9],
    [0, 3, 9, 7],
    [0, 3, 2, 9],
    [0, 3, 2, 0],
    ...
]
```

Represented as a tree, this is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: 1- how do you get the `[0,3,9,0]`? you only follow the path with the first column and take all the row? 2- When you reach the second column `0`->`2`-`0`->`2`, aren't caught in a loop?

Comment: The algo is supposed to stop at three iterations (if do not count 0):
 0 -> 2 -> 0 -> 2, but then it does not continue, and the next sequence should be  0 -> 2 -> 0 -> 5

Comment: added a recursive tree to better explain

Comment: Can you provide the complete output? (or let us know how many rows you expect) Also, can you draw on your schematic the path for `[0, 3, 2, 9]`? I don't get why the `3` is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use numeric naming for both rows and columns in your dataframe, it's faster to convert the frame to a 2-D numpy array. Try this;

```py
arr = df.to_numpy()

staging = [[0]]
result = []
while len(staging) > 0:
    s = staging.pop(0)
    if len(s) == 4:
        result.append(s)
    else:
        i = s[-1]
        for j in range(4):
            staging.append(s + [arr[i, j]])
```

Comment: OP is asking for a recursive solution.

Comment: @jurez OP asked to solve a recursive problem. My answer meets that requirement. Whether it actually use recursive function is irrelevant